# Some Start menu items become unlocalized after sysprep

Tags: windows-7, language, start-menu, sysprep

I successfully deployed Windows 7 on some computers.

Now, in the Start menu, some items are in French (the native installation language) and other are unlocalized. I can see `Welcome Center` and `displayswitch` icons.

Note that these icons where already here before doing `/oobe` or `/audit` along with `/generalize` or not.

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE** I just manually renamed icons, that worked.

Comment: I was going to suggest toggling the regional and language options between the 2 languages to see if that would reset everything.

Comment: Localization has always been a bastard child in Windows.  It reminds me of the blog posts about Swedish Windows.  In Sweden, apparently they constantly run into problems translating cause you'll have accounts like "Owner" and their corresponding group "Owners." Apparently, a lot of nouns in Swedish have the same written singular and plural form. . .  Still, better than other OSes.